# Поменять сортировку.

Tags: pascal, сортировка

Здравствуйте!

Не могу сообразить, как можно в отдельном куске кода поменять сортировку данную, на сортировку вставками. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как.

Кусок кода:

```
const dl=5; n=5; p='     ';
type word=packed array[1..dl] of char;
     mas = array[1..n] of word;
var sym: char; a: mas; r: word; i, j, k: integer;

procedure sort(var x: mas);
var j, k, l: integer; h, min: word;
begin
for j:=1 to n-1 do begin
      min:=x[j]; k:=j; for l:=j to n do if min>x[l] then begin
                                           min:=x[l]; k:=l; end;
                 h:=x[j]; x[j]:=x[k]; x[k]:=h; end;
end;
```

Спасибо.

Comment: @ХэшКод, как выбрать свой ответ верным?

Comment: @ВладиславМСК скорее всего никак во избежание кармадрочерства. Может, модераторы выберут

Comment: @DreamChild, Можно специально сделать, что за такие вещи - карма не изменяется. Просто хочется, чтобы люди быстрее находили решение. Чисто благие намерения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот верный рабочий код:

```
const slovo=5; n=5; p='     ';

type
    sl=packed array[1..slovo] of char;
    massiv = array[1..n] of sl;
var add: char;
    a: massiv;
    r: sl;
    i,j,k,nn: integer;

{Процедура сортировки вставками}
procedure InsertSort(var mass: massiv; var  n:integer);

var i, j, nom: integer; h, temp,  min: sl;

begin
for i:=1 to n-1 do
begin
nom:=i+1;
temp:=mass[nom];
for j:=i+1 downto 2 do
begin
if (temp<mass[j-1]) then
begin
mass[j]:=mass[j-1];
nom:=j-1;
end;
end;
mass[nom]:=temp;
end;

end;
```